# Is JDK7 safe to use now?

Tags: java, java-7

I have recently learned that there are bugs in JDK7 for hotspot compiler optimization. See 
[this thread](http://www.lucidimagination.com/search/document/1a0d3986e48a9348/warning_index_corruption_and_crashes_in_apache_lucene_core_apache_solr_with_java_7).

I don't quite understand the details of these bugs, but they seem to be related to loop optimization. Since I'm going to run some large-scale program in the -server mode (which of course contains a lot of loops), I wonder whether it would be safe to use JDK7 or not? Thank you.

Comment: Simple question: Has it been released yet as an official *sanctioned* version? Until then, I think the answer obvious in any mission-critical code.

Comment: @Hovercraft: sanctioned by who? It has certainly been officially released by Oracle and is the default and featured download at their Java pages.

Comment: @Thilo: that's not the official recommended Java version that I see on their download page. I see "Recommended Version 6 Update 26 (filesize: ~ 11 MB)"

Comment: Oracle obviously wants developers to use it. But it's not yet ready for release.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The same bug exists in JDK 6, but since the default optimization are different, it only comes into play when aggressive optimization flags are used.

To disable this optimization for JDK 7 use the -XX:-UseLoopPredicate flag and you will be safe across any version of JDK 7.

Answer (score 3):

You should start testing your code with JDK7 now.

As to whether you want to put it into production, it is probably always safe to wait a while. That does not just apply to the JDK, but to any major upgrade to any major piece of software.
Let them do their update1 and update2, and wait what Apache and others have to say for it.
You do not need to be in a hurry, right? JDK6 works ...

Comment: you *want* to, but whether it is a good idea depends on how long it is before your code needs to go into production.